# Conditional Probability give B

Tags: probability

The probability model for random variable A is:

[image]

The conditional probability model for random variable B given A is:

[image]

If $B = 3$, what is the conditional PMF $p_{A\mid B}(a\mid 3)$? 
Here what makes me confusing is: Does $p_A(a)$ will change depend on $B$ ? In my opinion $p_A(a)$ is not dependent of $B$ so my answer would be like $p_{A\mid B}(a\mid 3)=p_A(a)$ whether $B=3$ or not. but im not sure.

Comment: instead of editing 10 times, is here no one help to whether my correct or not?

Comment: Since B is dependent on A, then A is dependent on B, as $\mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid \mathcal B)\mathsf P(\mathcal B)=\mathsf P(\mathcal B\mid \mathcal A)\mathsf P(\mathcal A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just another application of Bayes' Rule (and the Law of Total Probability). 
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf p_{A\mid B}(a\mid b) & = \frac{\mathsf p_{A}(a)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(b\mid a)}{\mathsf p_B(b)}
\\[1ex]
 & =\frac{\mathsf p_A(a)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(b\mid a)}{\mathsf p_A(-4)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(b\mid-4)+\mathsf p_A(4)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(b\mid 4)}
\\[3ex]
\mathsf p_{A\mid B}(a\mid 3)  & =\frac{\mathsf p_A(a)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(3\mid a)}{\mathsf p_A(-4)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(3\mid-4)+\mathsf p_A(4)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(3\mid 4)}
\\[1ex]
 & =\begin{cases}\Box & : a=-4 \\ \Box & : a=4 \\ 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

---

Hint:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf p_A(4)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(3\mid 4) &= \frac 3 4\cdot\frac 1 2 = \frac 3 8
\\[1ex]
\mathsf p_A(-4)\mathsf p_{B\mid A}(3\mid -4) &= \frac 1 4\cdot\frac 2 3 = \frac 1 6
\end{align}$$

Comment: it looks like Denominator is equal to one and How i can Multiply that $P_A(a)$ and $P_{B|A}(3|a)$ ?

Comment: @Andy Evaluate at $a=4$ and at $a=-4$

Comment: Ohh That was really clear Thanks ^^ it seems problem is in my mind at this moment